# Javascript || não exibir um bloco dependendo do valor de um array

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde amigos!

Deixe-me explicar melhor o meu caso. No código que coloco em anexo, temos 6 inputs. A ideia é que o bloco `<p class="nome-plano">NEXT 60 ESPORTE</p>` não pode ser exibido se o valor de uma dessas 6 inputs for maior que 65. Vejam o código abaixo:

```js
const noSport = ()=> {
                let sportPlan = document.querySelectorAll('.nome-plano');
                if(sportPlan = "NEXT 60 ESPORTE") {
                    sportPlan.style.display = "none";
                }
            }

            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=> {
                let paxAge = document.querySelectorAll(".idade-viajantes");
                for (i=0;i<paxAge.length;i++){
                    let paxAgeValue = paxAge[i].value;
                    let paxAgeNumber = parseInt(paxAgeValue);
                    if(paxAgeNumber[i]>65) {
                        noSport();
                    }
                }
            });
```

```html
<label class="group"><span>Preencha abaixo a idade dos viajantes na data da viagem</span>
            <input name="idade" maxlength="2" class="idade-viajantes only-number" type="text" value="66">
            <input name="idade" maxlength="2" class="idade-viajantes only-number" type="text" value="">
            <input name="idade" maxlength="2" class="idade-viajantes only-number" type="text" value="">
            <input name="idade" maxlength="2" class="idade-viajantes only-number" type="text" value="">
            <input name="idade" maxlength="2" class="idade-viajantes only-number" type="text" value="">
        </label>

    <div>
        <div>
            <p class="nome-plano">NEXT 15</p>
            <p class="preco-plano">R$52</p>
        </div>

        <div>                          
            <p class="nome-plano">NEXT 60 ESPORTE</p>
            <p class="preco-plano">R$52</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Eu fiz um laço passando por cada uma das inputs e transformando seus valores de string para inteiros.

Minha ideia é que se um dos campos for um numero inteiro maior que 65 nós executamos a função `noSport()` que deve mudar o style do elemento para `display: none;`.

Porém não roda, e o console do browser não está me dando erro... Tentei também executar a função `noSport` como anonima mesmo aberto dentro do desvio condicional, mas não rodou também.

Em que estou pecando? deveria fazer um outro laço para verificar os valores individuais do array se são maior que 65? a forma como eu estou montando a função `noSport` está errada? Uma biblioteca como jQuery me ajudaria neste caso?
Se alguém puder me dar um força agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possíveis erros:

`DOMContentLoaded` pode não estar sendo disparado pois o DOM já foi carregado quando o JavaScript rodar.
Solução: verifique se a página já está carregada, e se não, adicione o event listener:

```
if (document.readyState === 'complete') start();
else document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', start);
```

`paxAgeNumber` é uma valor, não um array, não faz sentido acessar a posição `i` para compara-lo, penas compare o próprio `paxAgeNumber`:

```
if(paxAgeNumber[i] > 65) {
    noSport();
}
```

`sportPlan` é um array, no `if` você o trata como uma única variável. Não apenas isso, mas você atribui o valor 'NEXT 60 ESPORTE' para esse array ao invés de fazer uma comparação.

Minha sugestão:

```js
function noSport () {
  let sportPlan = document.getElementById('next60esportes');
  sportPlan.style.display = 'none';
}

function start() {
  let paxAges = document.getElementsByClassName('idade-viajantes');
  
  for (let paxAge of paxAges) {
    let paxAgeValue = paxAge.value;
    let paxAgeNumber = parseInt(paxAgeValue);
    
    if (paxAgeNumber > 65) {
      noSport();
      break;
    }
    
  }
}

if (document.readyState === 'complete') start();
else document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', start);
```

```html
<label class="group"><span>Preencha abaixo a idade dos viajantes na data da viagem</span>
            <input name="idade" maxlength="2" class="idade-viajantes only-number" type="text" value="66">
            <input name="idade" maxlength="2" class="idade-viajantes only-number" type="text" value="">
            <input name="idade" maxlength="2" class="idade-viajantes only-number" type="text" value="">
            <input name="idade" maxlength="2" class="idade-viajantes only-number" type="text" value="">
            <input name="idade" maxlength="2" class="idade-viajantes only-number" type="text" value="">
        </label>

    <div>
        <div>
            <p class="nome-plano">NEXT 15</p>
            <p class="preco-plano">R$52</p>
        </div>

        <div>                          
            <p id="next60esportes" class="nome-plano">NEXT 60 ESPORTE</p>
            <p class="preco-plano">R$52</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note que no seu código, o if está sendo feito como se `paxAgeNumber` fosse um array (utilizando o `[i]` para acessar um elemento), quando na verdade, na linha de cima, a variável é iniciada com um valor inteiro.

Portanto, o código deverá ser o seguinte:

```
if(paxAgeNumber>65) {
    noSport();
}
```